# Why is looping Python TCP receiver receives message partially?

Tags: python, tcp

I have a server that sends some messages to a client. The print(trades) statement shows that file reader reads the entire csv correctly:

```
    def send_past_trades(self):
        with open('OTC_trade_records.csv',newline='') as f:
            connectionSocket, addr = self.client
            trades = f.read()
            #print(trades)
            connectionSocket.send(trades.encode())
```

My client receiver is like this:

```
msg = b""
while(True):
    print("Batch receiving")
    tmp = client_socket.recv(4096)
    msg += tmp
    if len(tmp) < 4096:
        print(len(tmp))
        break
msg = msg.decode()
print(msg)
```

The message is always partial. I can see that the statement "Batch receiving" is printed once and when the break statement is initiated, the length of the last message is 1228.

Another point is, this code works fine in my local system. The problem occurs when I put the server program to a remote server machine. Is there a possibility that server intervenes with the message?

Note: I tried different ways to solve the problem such as sending only package size of 1024b messages in a loop. Still partial messages received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
if len(tmp) < 4096:
    print(len(tmp))
    break
```

The point is that `bufsize` in `recv(bufsize)` is a maximum size to receive. The `recv` will return fewer bytes if there are fewer available.

I suggest to define a simple communication protocol that describes the structure of a message with a header and payload. The header must contain the payload size. This allows you to parse data from the incoming TCP stream and get the exact size of the received data. Then you can receive requested amount of data.

A client will look like this:

```py
import struct

# Receive a header
header = connection.recv(8)
(length,) = struct.unpack('>Q', header)  # Parse payload length

# Receive the payload
payload = b''
while len(payload) < length:
    to_read = length - len(payload)
    payload += connection.recv(4096 if to_read > 4096 else to_read)
```

Server:

```py
import struct

with open('OTC_trade_records.csv',newline='') as f:
    connectionSocket, addr = self.client
    trades = f.read()
    length = struct.pack('>Q', len(trades))
    connectionSocket.sendall(length)
    connectionSocket.sendall(trades)
```

Comment: The loop runs once and in second run gets stuck at tmp = client_socket.recv(4096) after I changed my code.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. If you don't close the connection on the server side, a deadlock may occur. I corrected my answer.

Comment: My bad. I had a settimeout set from before somewhere else. Your suggestion works. Thank you

Comment: Why does a deadlock occur? Is it from the multiple threads running on the server side? And if so how does struct and sendall solve this?

Comment: Well, it is somewhat incorrect to call this deadlock. This is a normal behavior of blocking TCP receive. Client is waiting for any data on connected socket.

Comment: We are sending the size of the subsequent amount of data packed in a struct. Client receive this size to determine exactly how much data the server will send.